# I can't invoke object method from activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an object method instead of static in java

```
object StaticMethods{
fun clearProgressPreferences(sp: SharedPreferences, level:String, test:String){
    val edit = sp.edit()
    edit.putInt(level+test+"array_size", 0)
    edit.apply()
}
```

When i try to invoke it, i get the `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

The same thing with companion object of any classes

Comment: How do you invoke the method?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it static,just put `@JvmStatic` annotation before your function & call :

```
StaticMethods.clearProgressPreferences()
```

If you want to access it as it is then use like this :

```
StaticMethods.INSTANCE.clearProgressPreferences()
```